# Sum Of a column of generic list by passing column name anonymously

Tags: c#, linq, generics

My Code is like this

```
 private static void ShowSum(Label lbl, IEnumerable<dynamic> list, string columnName)
    {
        lbl.Text = list.Sum(x => x.columnName).ToString();
    }
```

I am trying to get the sum of a specific column each time when I call this function, Column name will be passed as a parameter to this function. As of now this is not working as `columnName` is interpreted as a string intead of specific column name. What is the correct approach to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know the strings (and type of the list) at compile time or are you getting the column name at run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use reflection to get a property from a dynamic object by it's name:

```
lbl.Text = list.Sum(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToString();
```

But I would recommend you to use strong types instead of dynamics. At least you will be able to catch some errors on compile-time instead of run-time.

Answer (score 1):

If you know to type of list at runtime:

```
private static void ShowSum<T>(Label lbl, IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, int> columnMapper)
    {
        lbl.Text = list.Sum(x => columnMapper(x)).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to know the types: for the parameter we can use `Func<dynamic, object> columnMapper`, then for the sum selector, `x => Convert.ToDouble((object)columnMapper(x))`. This will accept any anonymous type and allow the column to return any numeric type (or null).

Comment: That's true, but in situations where dynamic types aren't necessary we can have better performance (in this case because you need reflection) and type safety if we avoid using dynamic typing.